# AWS r53 mx record unable to create

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

i want to create mx record in aws r53 like this. my domain is in godadday

1) Host as @ and points to as smtp.secureserver.net with priority 0 and TTL one hour. 
2) Host as @ and points to as mailstore1.secureserver.net with priority 10 and TTL one hour.

bust while creating this error flash .The record set could not be saved because:
- The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your image is accurate, the priority needs to proceed the FQDN

Your example shows:

```
smtp.secureserver.net
```

And should be:

```
0 smtp.secureserver.net
```

The leading integer is the priority.

> An integer that represents the priority for an email server. If you specify only one server, the priority can be any integer between 0 and 65535. If you specify multiple servers, the value that you specify for the priority indicates which email server you want email to be routed to first, second, and so on. The server with the lowest value for the priority takes precedence. For example, if you have two email servers and you specify values of 10 and 20 for the priority, email always goes to the server with a priority of 10 unless it's unavailable. If you specify values of 10 and 10, email is routed to the two servers approximately equally.

The following worked for me

[image]

**Reference**
[Route53 MX Record Type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#MXFormat)

Comment: What those numbers 10 and 20 mean?

Comment: @SerhiiKushchenko I've added an explanation in the answer.  They are a priority number.  Explained above.